# Probability Continuous Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability

Choose a number at random between 0 and 1 and choose a second
number at random between 1 and 3. Find the prob. that their product is > 1

Here is what I have so far: 
Let x be the first number; let y be the second number. Then the pair
(x, y) is uniformly distributed in the rectangle 0 < x < 1, 1 < y < 3.

The total area: 2

I know that I have to use integration but I am confused on how to use it.

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture of the part of the rectangle consisting of those pairs $(x,y)$ with xy>1$.  Then find the area of that region.

Answer (score 1):

Draw coordinate axes, and the rectangle $R$ that you described. Draw the first quadrant part of the hyperbola $xy=1$.  Let $A$ the part of the first quadrant that is above the curve $xy=1$, but is contained in $R$.

Then our probability is $\frac{1}{2}$ times the area of $A$.

This area is not difficult to compute using an appropriate integral. A sketch will be helpful. It will show that the curve $y=\frac{1}{x}$ meets the line $y=3$ at $x=\frac{1}{3}$, and the line $y=1$ at $x=1$. So the required area is $\int_{x=1/3}^1 \left(3-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$.

Answer (score 1):

When you finish the integration in the other Answers,
you can use results of the following simulation and graph as a check.

```
 m = 10^6;  x = runif(m, 0, 1);  y = runif(m, 1, 3)
 w = x*y;  mean(w > 1)
 ## 0.451084          # approx P(W > 1), about 3 places.
```

The histogram shows a million simulated values of $W = X*Y$, suggesting the shape of the density function of $W$ (not requested).
The desired probability is to the right of the vertical blue line.
For clarity, the scatterplot at right shows only 15,000 points. The region
of integration is shown in blue. The 15,000 points are uniformly
distributed in the rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for $P(XY>1)=P\left(X>\dfrac{1}{Y}\right)$, which can be represented by the integral
$$\iint_D f(x,y)\,dA=\int_1^3\int_0^{1/y}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$
where $D$ is the region that John is referring to in his comment.

This is easy enough to compute if you can determine the joint distribution $f(x,y)$ (a simple task since you know $X$ and $Y$ are both uniformly distributed).